# How to drop columns that meet a certain pattern over a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I'm trying to drop columns that have a suffix .1 - indicating that this is a repeated column name. This needs to act over a list of dataframe

I have written a function:

```
drop_duplicated_columns <- function (df) {
  lapply(df, function(x) {
    x <- x %>% select(-contains(".1"))
    x
  })
  return(df)
}
```

However it is not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: you don't need to lapply, dplyr is already enough

Comment: Write that function first and then use `lapply(your_list, your_function)`. Might be worth looking at `?endsWith`

Comment: You can simply do `df[grepl('\\.1$', names(df))]`

Comment: You can improve the coding style as suggested by others but I think your code should work if you remove `return(df)` from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tidy way to solve this problem would be to first create a function that works for one data.frame and then map this function to a list

```
library(tidyverse)

drop_duplicated_columns <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    select(-contains(".1"))
}
```

Or even better

```
drop_duplicated_columns <- . %>% 
  select(-contains(".1"))
```

Usage in pipes, combine it with a map

```
list_dfs <- list(mtcars,mtcars)

list_dfs %>% 
  map(drop_duplicated_columns)
```

If you just need one function you can create a new pipe using the functioning code that you tested before

```
drop_duplicated_columns_list <- . %>%
  map(drop_duplicated_columns)


list_dfs %>% 
  drop_duplicated_columns_list()
```